# Setup a cron task that parses a friend's checkins on Facebook

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron

I want to setup a cron job that logs in to my facebook account, takes the latest checkin information for my friends, and then exports a JSON file with that information, so that I (and others) could use it somewhere else. As I have no experience with server-side scripting, do you think that this is possible? What would be an appropriate technology? I tried to use the [Python SDK](http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/) and I also had a look to [FBCMD](http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/) and [miniFB](http://code.google.com/p/minifb/) but I'm having most difficulties in creating a session with my account info hardcoded to the script - all the rest doesn't seem that hard to implement.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could point me to the right direction!

Comment: You could setup a cron to do a php script which gets your status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exact answer to my question, but a cleaner and more elaborate way to solve the same problem.
Facebook supports "[Real-time updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime)" on their Graph API:

> The Graph API supports real-time
>   updates to enable your application
>   using Facebook to subscribe to changes
>   in data from Facebook. Your
>   application caches data and receives
>   updates, rather than polling
>   Facebook’s servers. Caching data and
>   using this API can improve the
>   reliability of your application and
>   decrease its load times.

That did the trick in my case, without the need to use crontab or anything similar.